# SendOnBehalfOf still returns Bad Request (400) in docusign

Tags: python, rest, docusignapi

Trying to do simple SendOnBehalfOf in email request, and continue to get 400 status error on post.  Yes, I've read SOBO notes on RESTAPIGuide and following that, have confirmed that the user account being used to send (it's admin level) has all "Docusign API" settings toggled on under Permissions (I assume unnecessary, but also turned on same permissions for "otheruser" on whose behalf I want to send), and have narrowed down that the call works when I don't include the  node in the authentication credentials and fails when I do, as in the following...

these credential work:

```
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>adminUser@mydomain.com</Username><Password>thepass</Password><IntegratorKey>WXYZ-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

these don't:

```
<DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>otherUser@mydomain.com</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>adminUser@mydomain.com</Username><Password>thepass</Password><IntegratorKey>WXYZ-0000-0000-0000-0000-00000</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

I get 400 response with the later.

Many thanks in advance to pointing out what am I missing?

Comment: I don't think the XML format/contents that you posted is the problem, as I'm able to successfully execute a "GET Folder List" request -- either using SOBO OR without using SOBO -- both work for me using the exact same XML you posted (when inserting my users, pwd, and integrator key). Just curious -- what operation are you trying to execute using SOBO?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SOBO (Send On Behalf Of) functionality enabled on your account to be able to use it, and I think in this case that is what the issue was.  I think the DocuSign system should return an error message saying feature not enabled or something of that nature instead of returning a `400 bad request` when you try to use SOBO and it's not enabled.

The API Documentation does state this as well as the Dev Center -> Explore -> Features -> SOBO page with the following text:

"The DocuSign Send On Behalf Of functionality permits automated sending through the DocuSign API by an integrated sender on behalf of another sender. **The Send On Behalf Of functionality is only available to accounts that use the DocuSign API to send envelopes and can be enabled for an account member by a DocuSign Customer Administrator through the DocuSign console or by contacting your DocuSign Account Manger**."

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

So to resolve, you can contact your DocuSign account manager to get the option enabled, or you can reach out to DocuSign support at:  `support@docusign.com`.  Just make sure to tell them the environment you're working in (DEMO.docusign.net in this case)

Comment: In short, RTM folks! :-)  Thanks Ergin!